# Программа pomatez из snap стартует только после переустановки

Tags: ubuntu, electron

Коротко: pomatez запускается только первый раз после установки. Второй раз не запускается, но помогает переустановка через snap.

Теперь подробнее. Ставлю пакет pomatez на систему Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS: `sudo snap install pomatez`

После установки запускают из терминала `pomatez`, программа открывается и работает, но есть предупреждения:

```
(electron) 'systemPreferences.isDarkMode()' is deprecated and will be removed. Please use 'nativeTheme.shouldUseDarkColors' instead.

(pomatez:114027): Gtk-WARNING **: 21:22:28.819: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1566:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(pomatez:114027): Gtk-WARNING **: 21:22:28.823: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3616:25: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(pomatez:114027): Gtk-WARNING **: 21:22:28.824: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:4078:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name
21:22:29.595 › Checking for update
21:22:29.661 › Error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/snap/pomatez/2/resources/app-update.yml'
(node:114027) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/snap/pomatez/2/resources/app-update.yml'
(node:114027) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:114027) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
/usr/share/libdrm/amdgpu.ids: No such file or directory
```

Если выйти из программы, и попробовать запустить снова, то она не открывается, ошибок в консоли нет, `ps aux | grep pomat` - пусто.

Если удалить пакет `sudo snap remove pomatez` и снова поставить, программа снова работает, но только один раз.

Я в раздумьях: написать issue мейнтейнеру или это моя специфическая проблема, и ее как-то можно решить?

Comment: Я так понимаю - у тебя или видюха от амд или проц амд со встроенным видео?

Comment: Версию с канала `edge` пробовал ставить?

Comment: На сайте есть и классические пакеты и appimage. Они тоже не пашут?

Comment: @donRumata Да, видеокарта amd. Но это вряд ли относится к делу. Сделал `strace pomatez` и в логе нашел `need to run as root or suid`. WTF? Если запускать как `sudo pomatez` - программа работает. Я думаю еще больше покопаться через strace, нашел статью где пишут как отлаживать более сложные случаи.

Comment: `Версию с канала edge пробовал ставить?` - попробовал. Версия оказалась та же `1.1.0` (билд не указан, но md5 одинаковый), соответственно та же проблема.

Comment: `На сайте есть и классические пакеты и appimage. Они тоже не пашут?`. Поставил appimage - проблема ушла. Классический deb - также проблема решилась. Получается, проблема в snap сборке.

Comment: Ну может проблема ещё и в ошибке `/usr/share/libdrm/amdgpu.ids: No such file or directory`